# RUBY -Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 503 => Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable

Tags: ruby, mechanize, irb, mechanize-ruby

I tried looking for answers on other threads but didn't feel like the responses were relevant to my situation (I apologize if that's not the case). That said, I am trying to run a simple ruby script in irb

```
>     require 'mechanize'
>     
>     agent = Mechanize.new
>     
>     page = agent.get('https://www.amazon.com/')
```

Essentially I am trying to webscrape Amazon, and for some reason I am running into this error:

```
> Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 503 => Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable for
> https://www.amazon.com/ -- unhandled response
```

Has anyone ever encountered this before? I feel like the solution is simple, but I can't wrap my brain around it.

Thanks for your time,

-javi

Comment: They're probably throwing that error because they don't like your user_agent string.

Comment: the one where i declare a new instance of mechanize?

Answer (score 0):

> The Web server (running the Web site) is currently unable to handle
>   the HTTP request due to a temporary overloading or maintenance of the
>   server. The implication is that this is a temporary condition which
>   will be alleviated after some delay. Some servers in this state may
>   also simply refuse the socket connection, in which case a different
>   error may be generated because the socket creation timed out.

The above is what `503` means. And your output clearly states `Net::HTTPServiceUnavailable`

The error is not from your end. If I were you I'd actually confirming the destination server to see if it's up.